# Placement of DIV using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

In the right lower corner of the website there is a div containing a link to switch the language from german to english. This div is supposed to be always at the bottom of the screen. I tried using the JQuery Funktion Offset() to achieve this but I can't get it right. 
Maybe someone can help me.

The code: http://db.tt/gtgdgOeD
A screenshot: http://db.tt/v8FdAuRn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a CSS style:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `div`'s position to `fixed`, then the `bottom` and `right` css properties to `0`, and it will stay there.